# SQL - Last Day of Month

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a Table which looks like this:

```
DATE                  |   Number
01-01-16 00:00:00          10
02-01-16 00:00:00          10
03-01-16 00:00:00          11
04-01-16 00:00:00          12
05-01-16 00:00:00          13
....
31-01-16 00:00.00          15
........
29-02-16 00:00:00          18
```

I got this table for the last few months.
I now want to retrieve the value of the rows, which contain the last day of the previous month and the month before the last month. So for today I would like to retrieve the Value of the 31-1-16 and 29-2-16.

My result should look like:

```
  lastmonth                                    | lastmonth2 
   18-> Corresponding value to Date: 29-02-16  |  15 -> value for 31-01-16
```

Would appreciate any help.

Cheers

Comment: I don't follow the SQL. Why is the IF inside the LAST_DAY? And what exactly are you summing? There's no GROUP BY. Are you expecting one row per Number or just one row?

Comment: Can you confirm that dates are stored using a date data type?

Comment: Yes it's the "date" type.

Comment: The SQL without the Last_DAY Function was working fine for another table.. that's why I tried smth out, but it isn't working....

Comment: Why it's '15' in LastMonth2 ?

Comment: Beause 2 months ago was january. And the Value of Number for the lastday of the month January (31-01-16) is 15.

Comment: I don't understand what are you looking for, but DATE = YEAR(....) looks suspicious. YEAR gives you back the year from the date. It wont be equal to a date with days and month . Maybe YEAR(DATE) = YEAR(....)

Comment: I want to retrieve the Data of the last day of the month for the last 2 months. So for today: I want the values of the 31-1-16 and 30-2-16.

Comment: They should be stored in the alias lastmonth and lastmonth2

Comment: Ok I think i understood, i will try something.

Comment: Thank you all for your response. I have edited my Post, I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Gordon's code for determining the correct dates plus subqueries to fetch the Number values for those rows:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT Number FROM cc_open_csi_view
       WHERE last_day(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 month)) = date(`DATE`)) as lastmonth,
    (SELECT Number FROM cc_open_csi_view
       WHERE last_day(date_sub(curdate(), interval 2 month)) = date(`DATE`)) as lastmonth2
FROM DUAL;
```

Hope that's what you wanted! Works for me in a simple example. I don't know if you need the `date()` part around `DATE` but it seemed safest.

Comment: It is working! Thank you very much! And Gordon thank you too :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is logic for the last day of this month and the previous month:

```
select last_day(curdate()) as last_day_of_this_month,
       last_day(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 month)) as last_day_of_prev_month
```

You can get the last day of any month relative to the current month by changing the "1".

And, I have no idea what date "30-2-16".  When describing dates, you should use ISO standard formats.  The last day of February 2016 was 2016-02-29.

Comment: I think he wants the Number values that correspond to those dates in his table, although the schema isn't that clear to me (why the SUM etc.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I use this type of query, for my table I receive the last day of the last two months for every record in the table. I just want to retrieve the value of number for the last day of the previous month and the same for the previous previous month.

Comment: Yes Rup, I want the Data which corresponds to this dates.

Comment: "for every record in the table" - you only get one row. This is the full query, you don't add `FROM cc_open_csi_view`. If you're more comfortable having a FROM anyway then you can use `FROM DUAL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE 
           WHEN  last_day(curdate()) = `DATE` THEN number
       END as number_last_month,
       CASE 
           WHEN last_day(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 month)) = `DATE` 
                THEN number
       END as number_last_month2
 FROM cc_open_csi_view
```

I can't test it right now on sqlfiddle.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tested it and received only null values. I have 10k rows in this table and for every row I receive the null value. I only want 1 value for number_last_month and number_last_month2.